# Difference between git main and linked working tree?

Tags: git, git-worktree

Is there any difference between a "main working tree" and a "linked working tree" in git? If so, what differences are there?

---

Git has a subcommand called [git-worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) used to be able to manage multiple working trees in one repository. When cloned with this command:

```
git clone <url> --separate-git-dir=.git main
```

the directory `main` will contain the "main working tree". After that a new working tree can be created with `git worktree add temp`. `temp` is now a "linked working tree".

Is there any way to tell the difference of the two types? One thing should be that `main` can not be removed in the same way as `temp` (`git worktree remove temp`). But are there other things that are possible/impossible to do with one kind of the worktree and not the other?

Comment: `git worktree list` always prints the main working tree in the first line.

Comment: You separated the `.git` directory, so my guess is that `/local/repo` is showing you where the `.git` directory for the `main` worktree is.

Comment: @RichardSmith I separated the questions regarding that into its own question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583149/why-is-the-folder-that-contains-git-dir-still-associated-in-some-ways-with-th

Comment: Seems that torek answered your question fully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible-vs-impossible: the answer *should* be no, in general.  The only restriction on the main working tree is that you cannot remove it.

Actual: yes, occasionally other bits show through.  For instance, when acting as the receiver of a `git push`, at least in older versions of Git, only the main working tree's branch was considered.  (This may still be the case; I have not tested it.)

Git has to distinguish internally between "main" and "added" working tree because the traditional location of traditional files is directly in `.git`: e.g., `.git/HEAD` contains the main working tree's current branch and `.git/index` contains the main working tree's default index.  Other added working trees have their `HEAD` and index files elsewhere.  This is the source of those differences that "leak out" of Git.  They are not *intended* to leak, but sometimes they do.