# Why is the folder that contains `.git` dir still associated in some ways with the main worktree folder when using separate git dir?

Tags: git

After cloning a repo with the separate git dir option the root folder acts strange in git version `2.31.0`.

```
/local/repo> git clone <url> --separate-git-dir=.git main
```

After this command, the dir structure is:

```
/local/repo
  /.git
  /main
```

For some commands the `/local/repo` still seems associated with the worktree at `/local/repo/main`. For example:

---

**switch**

```
/local/repo> git switch banana
Switch to branch 'banana'
D       a_file_in_the_repo.txt
```

It's possible to switch branch of the main working tree when standing at `/local/repo`, but when doing so *ALL* files in the repository are listed as deleted (`D`) (since they are not available with relative path from the current directory `/local/repo` I guess, but really `/local/repo/main` should have been used here I think?). Isn't this strange?

---

**worktree list -v**

```
/local/repo> git worktree list -v
/local/repo       <hash0> [main]
```

Why is the worktree for main listed at `/local/repo` and not `/local/repo/main`?

---

**branch -vv**

```
/local/repo>git branch -vv
main <hash0> [origin/main] <commit message>
```

Why is the local dir for worktree not printed when standing at `/local/repo`? Expected output:

```
/local/repo>git branch -vv
main <hash0> (/local/repo/main) [origin/main] <commit message>
```

Comment: That's basically a behavioral bug. Whether it's fixable at all, and how difficult it is *to* fix, is another question entirely.